# Apply default class to all types of *n*

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply a `class` by default to an element? Let's say for example I wanted to apply the class `foo` to all `input` elements:

```
.foo { ... }
```

My limited knowledge leads me to believe I need to mark that up every single time:

```
<input type='text' class='foo' />
<input type='password' class='foo' />
...
```

But, clearly I was hoping I could apply that class by default to all `input` elements in the CSS somehow. I look forward to your answers!

### UPDATE

In an attempt to clarify myself, I do not want to duplicate the CSS that already exists for `foo` because I wouldn't want to have to change that in multiple places if I needed to change the style for `foo`. Further, I will be applying it to more than just all `input` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to take all the styles in your `.foo` rule and apply them to `input`s as well, just select both of them:

```
.foo, input { ... }
```

Comment: Okay, so this makes a lot of sense, thanks. Question though, and I should have clarified better, but the style I want applied exists in a jQuery UI custom stylesheet and I was ***trying*** to avoid modifying that sheet. Is there a way I can build an extended style in my sheet to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @BigM: That's not possible with standard CSS I'm afraid, only with a preprocessor (see beanland's answer). Even then, I'm not sure if you can grab rules from other stylesheets and put them in a Sass/LESS stylesheet either.

Comment: So, since I'm probably ***not*** going to download that custom stylesheet again *anyway*, this is really the best approach, and I should just modify the sheet and make future updates (if that even exists) by hand?

Comment: @BigM: I would recommend doing this in a script instead. (I'd originally commented on one of the other answers saying using a script was overkill, but since you've just mentioned that you're using jQuery UI, perhaps it's worth considering after all. You may also want to retag your question to that effect.)

Comment: I had considered using jQuery as well, but after hearing your answer here it made me question, what is the likelihood I'm going to **ever** get some kind of updates from jQuery UI for this stylesheet? Thoughts? Because it made me see it from a different perspective and I'm thinking simply appending those elements is a *very* good approach.

Comment: That I have no clue :/ I've never paid attention to that sort of thing.

Comment: I think you're thoughts here are the right approach in my situation, I'm going to extend the jQuery UI stylesheet and keep it simple. Thanks a lot, and great perspective!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to elements easily using a framework like jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').addClass('foo');
});
```

**EDIT**: To address your latest update...

If you want to "extend" a class for only certain conditions, you can add a second class for that case... e.g.:

```
<input class="foo bar" />

<style type="text/css">
    .foo.bar {
        color: #123;
    }
</style>
```

This will only apply your elements that are both `.foo` and `.bar`, and won't affect global `.foo` styles, which will still be applied to all `.foo` elements (including these)

Comment: I have considered the jQuery approach, and I'm still considering it, I"m just trying to finish thinking that through. Regarding the pseudo extension via wrapping the elements -- overall I'm going for less markup (I didn't even want to markup all the elements with `class='foo'` -- so that's a less attractive approach for me at this point.

Comment: I see... I guess I misunderstood your question.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I may not have been clear enough either -- it is easy to omit things that are important for outsiders -- +1 anyhow because they are in fact solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript's `document.getElementsByTagName(tag);` function.

Example:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(i = 0;i<tags.length;i++){
    tags[i].className = "foo";
}
```

If you want to keep the current classes on it just make sure to do `if(tags[i].className != ""){tags[i].className = tags[i].className + " foo";}`. It'll carry over the current classes.

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking into a stylesheet preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). These will allow you to use variables and other tricks here and there to help you avoid duplicating CSS. There are Javascript implementations of these as well as server-side ones if you would like to process it before giving it to the user.

Of course, the CSS ends up with duplicate code anyway, but you wouldn't have to write the same thing twice yourself.

For example, in LESS:

```
.foo {
   color: #222222;
   padding: 10px;
}

input {
   .foo;
}
```

Comment: You know, I've to date stayed away from these frameworks, but the more I hear about them the more I'm interested. I'm going to be checking them out to understand how they can benefit me, that's for sure.

Comment: I was hesitant at first, too, but boy does it save time! LESS has been a tremendous help in trimming down redundancies.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=text]{
  color:#123;
}
```

this is the code to apply css

Comment: In this instance it wouldn't affect the password field, which  the OP also wants.

Comment: you may use it for paassword too